# SQL Server - AFTER UPDATE vs FOR UPDATE?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to understand whats the difference between `after update` and `for update` triggers?

I know that `instead of` triggers can just override my current action.

But I don't see any difference between `after update` and `for update`

Comment: Docs on [creating a trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - only tiny diff is that you can't define `AFTER` on views.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`after update` and `for update` are synonyms for the same behavior, namely that the trigger fires after the update operation.

Answer (score 6):

**They are identical.**

[From msdn page on CREATE TRIGGER:](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703231044/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx)

> AFTER is the default, if FOR is the only keyword specified.

SQL Server allows a lot of flexibility in syntax.  All of the following are equivalent to each other as well:

- `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`
- `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN`
- `INSERT ...` and `INSERT INTO ...`
- `Table AS alias` and `Table alias`